# After upgrading to Windows 8.1 the themes from Windows 8 were replaced by new ones

Tags: windows-8, themes, windows-8.1-upgrade

I have searched in `C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\Web\Wallpaper` but it does not contain all the old Windows 8 themes.

Does anyone know another way to retrieve them?

Comment: You can get them from an existing Windows 8 machine I suppose.  This is typical behavior old themes are replaced with new ones.

Answer (score -1):

the theme files are located in /Windows/Resources.

if the Windows 8.0 *.MSStyles file won't run in 8.1, copy out all the pngs from that 8.0 file, into the 8.1 *.MSStyles file with a resource editor.

Comment: If you provide instructions on how to extract the files with a resource editor I will removed the downvote.

Comment: Honestly, the quickest way to extract them is to use 7-Zip, unfortunately 7-Zip can't add png images to a PE executable (exe, dll, scr, etc) so you'll have to use a resource editor (MAKE SURE your resource editor supports 64 bit executables (assuming you're using a 64 bit OS, if you're not it doesn't matter), some of them don't and they'll totally mangle the executable)

Or, you can skip all of that trouble and use Vista Style Builder.