# How can I get the default theme from Windows 8 in my upgraded 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, themes

I upgraded to Windows 8.1, and it comes with a theme installed that I don't like.  I loved the blue background/white flower theme that came installed on Windows 8 originally, but it seems to have vanished.

I've browsed through the `windows.old` folder but I don't see anything in there to recover it.

Is there a way to get this back?

Comment: Did you try looking in `Windows.old\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows` and `Windows.old\Windows\Resources\Themes`?

Comment: @and31415 all folders in there are empty. my taskbar is no longer transparent anymore either, which is confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After upgrading to Windows 8.1 the themes from Windows 8 were replaced by new ones](http://superuser.com/questions/670463/after-upgrading-to-windows-8-1-the-themes-from-windows-8-were-replaced-by-new-on)

Comment: Have you access to either a Windows 8 machine or a Windows 8 setup media?